# How to hide some parts in .Net 4.7?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

I'm working at a property management website. There are sold properties that i don't want to show to the users. What should I do with it? Should I make changes in the controller or the view?

This is my Sold properties controller code.

```
public ActionResult ViewSoldProperties()
    {
        ViewBag.Principles = db.UCDs.GetUCDs(UCLTypes.PropertyStatus).AsUcdSelectList();

        var propertiesViewAll = db.Properties.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false && x.Status == 2353).OrderByDescending(i => i.ID);
        var ucds = db.UCDs.AsNoTracking().ActiveOnly().ToList();
        foreach (var i in propertiesViewAll)
        {
            i.StatusName = ucds.Where(x => x.ID == i.Status).Select(t => t.Title).FirstOrDefault();

            i.FinancingName = ucds.Where(x => x.ID == i.Financing).Select(t => t.Title).FirstOrDefault();

            System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://gis.hcpafl.org/propertysearch/#/search/basic/address=" + i.StreetAddress + " " + i.RouteAddress + ", " + i.City);
            //Address2 is used as base address
            i.Address2 = client.BaseAddress.ToString();
            var compId = db.BuyingInfoes.Where(x => x.PropertyID == i.ID).Select(x => x.CompanyID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (compId != null)
            {
                var compAbbr = db.Owners.Where(x => x.ID == compId).Select(x => x.CompanyAbbreviation).FirstOrDefault();
                if (compAbbr != null)
                {
                    i.OwnerAbbriviation = compAbbr;
                }
            }
        }
        ViewBag.data = propertiesViewAll;
        //if (NumberOfRecords != null)
        //{
        //    return PartialView("PartialViewAll");
        //}
        return View();
```

Below are the images I want to hide from the customers on the live website.

[These are the example images I don't want to show to the users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEIf6.png)

Comment: Hey Faizan, welcome. For me it's not clear what you mean by "sold properties". If you want to select your items (yours "i" in foreach), then define the selection. If you wan't to change appereance of these items then you could use another type/class for this. OT: Maybe you would find some interesting hints here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines

Comment: OT: Why are you creating a new `HttpClient` instance, setting its base address to a fixed string, copying that value out again, and then throwing the instance away? You could just use `i.Address2 = new Uri("http://gis.hcpafl.org/propertysearch/#/search/basic/address=" + i.StreetAddress + " " + i.RouteAddress + ", " + i.City).ToString();` instead.